# Can I change the simulator order in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

As title... 
The simulator list is too long,
the default order of the list seems like order by alphabet,

If I want "iPhone Simulator" to show on the top, any method?

[image]

Comment: That looks like 50GB of simulators, ha!

Answer (score 1):

It's a very old question, but I will answer if anyone needs it.

**Yes, it is totally possible.**

[Xcode with sorted simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN4Pb.png)

It's not easy, but it's posssible. You will need to delete all existing simulators through "Devices and Simulators".

[Devices and Simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIvX5.png)

Then you must recreate one at a time, in the order you want, from top to bottom, numbering them so that they are in the order.

No use renaming, it will stay in the order it was created. Create numbered, because in the creation it will put in the order you think necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not order by alphabet, I check it. I think, you can just remove redundant simulators.

[image]